# MySQL composite foreign key only one column used

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL (Server version: 10.3.22-MariaDB MariaDB Server). When I create a composite foreign key, it seems that only the first column of the foreign key is in effect. Here, Emails references Persons via (firstname, lastname):

```
create table Persons (
firstname varchar(10),
lastname varchar(10),
dob date,
primary key (firstname, lastname)
) engine=innodb;

create table Emails (
firstname varchar(10),
lastname varchar(10),
email varchar(100),
foreign key (firstname, lastname) references Persons(firstname, lastname)
) engine=innodb;
```

When I do "desc Emails", I get

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| firstname | varchar(10)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| lastname  | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The MUL is marked only for firstname. I inserted the following:

```
insert Persons (firstname, lastname) values ("John", "Doe");
insert Persons (firstname, lastname) values ("John", "Smith");
insert Emails (firstname, lastname, email) values ("John", "Doe", "a@b.com");
insert Emails (firstname, email) values ("John", "c@d.com");
```

and when I do a "select * from Persons,Emails", I get

```
+-----------+----------+------+-----------+----------+---------+
| firstname | lastname | dob  | firstname | lastname | email   |
+-----------+----------+------+-----------+----------+---------+
| John      | Doe      | NULL | John      | Doe      | a@b.com |
| John      | Smith    | NULL | John      | Doe      | a@b.com |
| John      | Doe      | NULL | John      | NULL     | c@d.com |
| John      | Smith    | NULL | John      | NULL     | c@d.com |
+-----------+----------+------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

which shows that ("John", "Doe") of Emails is joined with ("John", "Smith") of Persons (second row). It seems that lastname is not used for the joining.

Am I doing foreign keys wrongly?

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be useful

Answer (score 0):

The manual page for [`DESCRIBE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/describe/) points to the manual page for [`SHOW COLUMNS`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-columns/) where the `Key` columns is described:

> The **Key** field indicates whether the column is indexed:
>
> - If **Key** is empty, the column either is not indexed or is indexed only as a secondary column in a multiple-column, non-unique index.
> - ...
> - If **Key** is ***MUL***, multiple occurrences of a given value are allowed within the column. The column is the first column of a
>   non-unique index or a unique-valued index that can contain `NULL`
>   values.

So your interpretation isn't necessarily true. An index on `(firstname, lastname)` can well exist.
Then member columns of an index don't need to be foreign keys.

And "`select * from Persons,Emails`" is a cross join. That just combines every row of one table with every row from the other table. So *every* e-mail is combined with *every* person.

If you want to combine people with their e-mail you need to do an inner join or a left join. But you should use modern, explicit join syntax with the `JOIN` keyword and an `ON` clause rather than the old style listing the tables in the `FROM` clause. For example an inner join:

```
SELECT *
       FROM persons p
            INNER JOIN emails e
                       ON p.firstname = e.firstname
                          AND p.lastname = e.lastname;
```

For more information about joins do some research.

And as a side note: Using the first and last name as a primary key for people isn't a very smart idea. Sooner or later there will be two different people with exactly the same name. And then you cannot store the second one. If this design should be used for something productive later, you need to revise it.